# How does stability analysis of Lotka-Volterra system differ from stability analysis on a normalized version?

Tags: dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes

How does stability analysis of Lotka-Volterra system differ from stability analysis on a normalized version?

Normalized LV system is such where the coefficients have been "aggregated" so that the system has less variable parameters. I find it confusing to infer how it alters critical points though, since:

- Since it's essentially describing the same system, then it should have same critical points.
- However the new parametrization may give different critical points than the original parametrization due to them having been shifted by the aggregating of coefficients.

I saw text that did stability analysis on normalized system and made it seem as if it's "as informative" as studying the original system. And I didn't understand why:

https://www.maths.dur.ac.uk/%7Ektch24/term1Notes(10).pdf, p. 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rescaled equation does not give new critical points. Notice that
$$\hat x = 1 = \frac d c x \implies x = \frac c d,$$
$$\hat y = 1 = \frac b a y \implies y = \frac a b$$
and $(x,y) = (\frac c d , \frac a b)$ is a steady state of the non-normalize equations.
The normalized system gives the same information because essentially, the parameters $a,b,c,d$ are "summarized" in $\gamma$ (I am using the notations from your reference) and $\hat x, \hat y$ are a percentage, essentially.